# SonarQube: Ignore files in current (root) directory

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

The documentation of the project, instructs on how to e.g. exclude (or include) in an analysis process, say all files under a directory:

```
mydir/**/*
```

or all files with a specific extension (say `.js`) under a directory:

```
mydir/**/*.js
```

But what is the way to **exclude** all `*.js` files in the **current** (the root) directory.

I have tried the following patterns. do not seem to work:

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=./*.js

sonar.coverage.exclusions=*.js
```

Comment: for analysis exclusion you should use `sonar.exclusions` parameter- reff. to [SonarQ doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters), `sonar.coverage.exclusions` is for code coverage only.

Answer (score 1):

The multi-directory pattern, `**`, can be used at any point in the regex.

- To exclude all `.js` files, you would use: `**/*.js`
- To exclude `.js` files only in the current directory: `*.js`

However

You should not try to set these values in your analysis properties. Doing so correctly is tricky. Use the UI to set these values instead.